# How can I select only the dummy variable columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Is there a way to select only those columns in a dataframe where the values in the columns are either 0 or 1 at a time?

I have a data frame with various values, including various strings as well as numbers.

I tried to use dplyr select but could not find a way to evaluate the values contained in the columns.

Sample data is shown below.

```
data %>% 
  tribble(
    ~id, ~gender, ~height, smoking,
    1, 1, 170, 0,
    2, 0, 150, 0,
    3, 1, 160, 1
  )
```

Comment: Your `data %>% tribble(.)` doesn't make sense to me, `tribble` doesn't take a frame as input like that; and `smoking` should be `~smoking`.

Comment: Sorry. I was a bit mistaken. Anyway, thank you very much. The problem has been solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function (or rlang-tilde function) to `select_if`, and look for columns that only contain `0:1`.

```r
tribble(
    ~id, ~gender, ~height, ~smoking,
    1, 1, 170, 0,
    2, 0, 150, 0,
    3, 1, 160, 1
  ) %>%
  select_if(~ all(. %in% 0:1))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   gender smoking
#    <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1      1       0
# 2      0       0
# 3      1       1
```

If you may have `NA` in a dummy-variable column, you may want to instead use `%in% c(0:1, NA)` in the predicate.